# Proof of the "Maz identity" for solving integrals

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The "Maz identity" states:
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}\{f\}(u)\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{g\}(u)\mathrm{d}u, $$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform.

I came across this identity when trying to find the Mellin transform of $\sin(x)$. The theorem turns out to be very useful, but I could not find any reference for a proof of this identity. The only references on MSE are [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179582/showing-int-0-infty-frac1-3-cos-2x2-cos-3xx2-dx-0/4228972#4228972) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989935/evaluating-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-fracx-cos-x-sin-xx3-cos/3565180#3565180), but neither provides a derivation. This identity also appears in a recent IG [post](https://www.instagram.com/p/CtR8FOWRuPC/) by owenmmth, for those who are interested.

PS: Although not important to the question, but the Mellin transform is defined as
$$ \{\mathcal{Mf}\}(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x .$$

Comment: There is a simple proof on wikipedia, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems

Comment: There was a guy on some Facebook math groups who's initials were AZ and somehow 
self-attributed and popularized [these 2 identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis). Their profession also happens to be a Mathematical Engineer - hence the "M" in MAZ. 


I guess. there are a lot of copy-writers on Instagram and other socials which spread this name, but as it didn't become really popular it often causes confusions - so it'll be better to use the name found on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Zacky would it be wise for me to adopt this name if I ever come to use it in a formal paper? After hearing your explanation, I don't feel that the name is very authorative.

Comment: In short, no. It's best to avoid any possible confusions in articles, and this name isn't reliable + probably there are very few who are aware of it. I would simply call it a property of the Laplace transform and write the definition explicitly (and as for references I'd give a web.archive link to Wikipedia since I'm not aware of an authoritative one), but others may advise you better as I have no experience in writing math papers.

Answer (score 1):

As Zima pointed out in the comment, Wikipedia's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) on the Laplace transform gives a nice proof, so I thought I would answer my own question for others who happen to search for this.

Start by showing that

$$ \int_0^\infty h(x) \{\mathcal{L}g\}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \{\mathcal{L}h\}(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x. $$

This is obvious from the definition of the Laplace transform and an application of Fubini's theorem:

$$ \begin{align} 
\int_0^\infty h(x) \{\mathcal{L}g\}(x)\mathrm{d}x 
&= \int_0^\infty h(x) \int_0^\infty g(u)e^{-ux}\mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}x \\ 
&= \int_0^\infty g(u) \int_0^\infty h(x)e^{-ux}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}u \\ 
&= \int_0^\infty \{\mathcal{L}h\}(u)g(u)\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_0^\infty \{\mathcal{L}h\}(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x .
\end{align} $$

Now make the substitution $h(x) = \{\mathcal{L}^{-1}f\}(x)$, so that $\{\mathcal{L}h\}(x) = f(x)$:

$$ \int_0^\infty \{\mathcal{L}^{-1}f\}(x) \{\mathcal{L}g\}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x. $$

This proves the useful Laplace transform identity.

Answer (score 0):

May this [paper](https://ijpam.uniud.it/online_issue/202044/71%20RamiAlahmad.pdf) answer your question?

*NB: there are typos in the last Corollary.*

Comment: The link doesn’t work for me sadly. Would it be possible for you to give a summary of the results in the paper?

Comment: @Jono94, Sorry, my bad! I fixed it and please check now.